# Umbraco menu macro creating duplicates

Tags: firefox, xslt, macros, umbraco

I'm having problems with a menu macro in Umbraco..

My macro returns a ul with li elements, one for each page.

```
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
<xsl:variable name="level" select="1"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

<ul>
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@isDoc and @level=$level]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
  <li>
    <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
      <xsl:if test="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::*/@id = current()/@id">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">selected</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
    </a>
  </li>
</xsl:for-each>
</ul>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem that I've encountered is that two pages are duplicated even though I only have one of each and the links on them work and point ot the same page.

I also have another problem and that is that the last li element is missplaced, but only on Firefox...Chrome and Safari work fine...

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Bek, Any chance you can post your edit as an answer so it's obvious that the question has actually been answered and to help people in future. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was annoyingly simple, just "republish entire site" and all problems were history. My guess is that some stuff got stuck in the cache...

Comment: Hi Bek, can you accept your own answer. For future information, the XSLT is run against the umbraco.config file, which is an XML file cache in the ~/App_Data directory. Occassionally this cache requires a "forceful" update using the "Republish entire site" option.